# Removing white space in HTML images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've reached quite a dilemma. I have an Image that I want to take up the background of a webpage. I want it to stretch across the screen width and height, and stay that size. When I use an `<img>` tag, I can't figure out how to stretch it to screen without white bars. wspace and hspace are deprecated in HTML5, so those don't work. Also, I tried implementing it into a CSS style, but I need to fade out the ENTIRE page with jQuery later on, and that isn't possible with putting the image in the CSS with `background-image`. Currently I am using this to implement the picture:

```
<img class='background' src='Images/backgroundImg.jpg'/>
```

The background class looks like this:

```
.background {
                max-height:100%;
                max-width:100%;
            }
```

What should I add to make the picture take the screen up entirely and still be possible to interact with it via jQuery? Thanks guys!

Comment: Go ahead and use `background-image:url(images/backgroundImg.jpg);` on the `body` element in CSS. Then, have all the content of the `body` in a wrapper `div` that has a `background-color` CSS set to black or white (whicever you'll want to fade to later). Set that opacity of that `div` initially to 0. When it comes time to fade the page out, just apply the effect to the `div` by fading the opacity to 1.

Comment: why isn't fading possible with a div with a background-image style setting?

Comment: The method that I was using required access to the image directly, using some of the other alternatives on the answers page worked out

Answer (score 1):

No need for max-height and max width, just height and width and positioning. Try:

```
.background {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
```

or you want a sticky positioned image:

```
.background {
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
```

Comment: Appears to function properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`object-fit`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) property with value `cover`. Note, make sure to check out the browser support tables, as IE does not support it at the moment.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qg4bdkp/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports">
```

Comment: A good alternative to the other answers. This is what I will be using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background: url(../Content/Images/wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;//scretch image
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fade out issue.

Comment: I don't believe that I can interact with the full image with jQuery if it is stored in a CSS style.

Comment: why not store it in that style? replace img with div

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is all that you need:

```html
    <style>
    html { 
      background: url(http://cdn7.viralscape.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Manhattan-City-Line-at-night-New-York.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
```

You just need to change the link that is there, with the path to the picture you want to use (`Images/backgroundImg.jpg`)!

### Edit:

To fade the entire page all you need to use is this:

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
```

CSS:

```
#overlay{
    opacity:3;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can use jquery to just change `display: none;` to `display: inline-block;` or whatever!

Comment: @TaylorBrown I added an edit that explains how to do the fade thing that you wanted!